# Three.js - OrbitControls doesn't work

Tags: javascript, three.js

If I run the script, the console displays me "THREE.OrbitControls is not a constructor".

[image]

What did I wrong? I used the same code from a manual.

```
var controls;
    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );
    controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );

var render = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame( render );
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
                //Hier wird die Größe des Fensters manipuliert!
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth - 20, window.innerHeight - 20);
```

};

```
    var animate = function () {
        requestAnimationFrame( animate );
        controls.update();                  
    };


var geometry1 = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 10, 10, 10);
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {specular: "#fdfb57", color: "#d8d613", emissive: "#6b6a0d", side: THREE.DoubleSide} );
var box = new THREE.Mesh(geometry1, material);


scene.add(box);   

camera.position.z = 50;


render();   
animate();
```

Comment: Did you include it? `<script src="js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>`

Comment: Put in in a fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You must explicitly include `OrbitControls` in your application. For example:

```html
<!-- Import maps polyfill -->
<!-- Remove this when import maps will be widely supported -->
<script async src="https://unpkg.com/es-module-shims@1.3.6/dist/es-module-shims.js"></script>
    
<script type="importmap">
    {
        "imports": {
            "three": "https://unpkg.com/three/build/three.module.js",
            "three/addons/": "https://unpkg.com/three/examples/jsm/"
        }
    }
</script>
```

```js
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js';
```

Also, read the comments in the three.js `OrbitControls` example carefully so you understand when to use

```
controls.addEventListener( 'change', render ); // add this only if there is no animation loop (requestAnimationFrame)
```

and when to use

```
controls.update(); // required if controls.enableDamping = true, or if controls.autoRotate = true
```

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/misc_controls_orbit.html

three.js r.147

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the *no animation loop* / `requestAnimationFrame` part!

Comment: Is there a CDN URL for OrbitControls.js?

Comment: That was my exact issue as i did not have an animation loop. Saved me time there

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue with a `webpack` build of the `three` library

```
var THREE = require('three')
THREE.OrbitControls === undefined  // true
```

Solution, install a 3rd party orbit control

```
npm install three-orbit-controls
```

details here: https://github.com/mattdesl/three-orbit-controls

then change the above code fragment to

```
var THREE = require('three')
var OrbitControls = require('three-orbit-controls')(THREE)
OrbitControls === undefined  // false
```

ok, not the best example, but when applied in place of `THREE.OrbitControls`, it works just fine ;)

Comment: This package has been merged to the primary repo and is no longer maintained - the current file is https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/commits/master/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js

Answer (score 6):

https://github.com/nicolaspanel/three-orbitcontrols-ts :

```
npm install --save three-orbitcontrols-ts
import { OrbitControls } from 'three-orbitcontrols-ts'
```

`orbitcontrols` should be installed separately in angular, this issue bothers me for several days.

Answer (score 2):

I have a same problem too, it's because you put in wrong line.
you need to put it under of this line

```
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
```

then you add orbit controls

```
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
controls.addEventListener( 'change', posUpdate );
controls.update();
```

if it wasn't work, add the script file download [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js)

```
<script src="OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue and after lot of research, the below thing worked

In your HTML the order matters when adding OrbitControls as it needs certain things from Three.js.

It should be

```
<script src="../build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```